# When does timing start for evaluating badges that are obtained based on daily activity?

Tags: discussion, badges, timezone

There are certain badges such as Mortarboard and Suffrage which are obtained by accomplishing something in a single day. For example, Suffrage is obtained by voting on 30 posts a day.

My query is, what time range is covered in a day?

Is it GMT, UTC, a user's local time or something else?

Or is it based on activities within last 24 hours and given whenever ever the user crosses a particular threshold. For example, I upvoted a post now and have done this 29 more times within the last 24 hours, hence I will get the Suffrage badge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SO uses UTC.

00:00 UTC -> 23:59 UTC is one day.

You can see the UTC timestamp of any post by hovering over the relative times.